# jar conflict in hbase coprocessor

Tags: jar, jackson, hbase, conflict

We use jackson(jackson-core,jackson-databind and jackson annotations, version is 2.8.6) in hbase endpoint, when the program is running, we got exception as following:

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonProcessingException
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2228)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:112)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:133)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:108)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonProcessingException
at com.xxxxx.xxxxx.server.xxx.xxx.xxx(xxx.java:73)
at com.xxxxx.xxxxx.server.xxx.xxx.xxx(xxx.java:157)
at com.xxxxx.xxxxx.server.xxx.xxx.xxx(xxx.java:52)
at com.xxxxx.xxxxx.server.xxx.xxx.xxx(xx.java:38)
at com.xxxxx.xxxxx.server.coprocessor.xxx.xxx(xxx.java:52)
at com.xxxxx.xxxxx.common.rpc.msg.StartExecution$StartExecutionService.callMethod(StartExecution.java:1749)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.execService(HRegion.java:7864)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execServiceOnRegion(RSRpcServices.java:1991)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execService(RSRpcServices.java:1973)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:33652)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2180)
... 4 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.CoprocessorClassLoader.loadClass(CoprocessorClassLoader.java:310)
... 15 more

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:95)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.getRemoteException(ProtobufUtil.java:329)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.execService(ProtobufUtil.java:1634)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel$1.call(RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.java:104)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel$1.call(RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.java:94)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:136)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.callExecService(RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.java:107)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CoprocessorRpcChannel.callBlockingMethod(CoprocessorRpcChannel.java:73)
... 27 more
```

It seems like a jar conflict between coprocessor and hbase. Does anyone has met this problem?